# Print result of a loop in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

This code doesn't work. I get the following errors (in eclipse) that I can't seem to resolve:

> Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
>   Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
>   Duplicate local variable interest

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhile {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("balance: ");
        int balance = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("interestRate: "); 
        double interestRate = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("year: ");
        int year = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("input: ");
        String input = in.next();
        Integer interest = null;    //to define interest    

        do 
        { 
            double interest = balance * interestRate / 100;
            balance += interest;
            year++; // print current balance
        }
        while (input.equals("N"));
        System.out.println("interest: " + interest + "balance: " + balance + "year: " + year) ;
    };
}
```

Comment: If you fixed your indentation it would be easier to see the problem.

Comment: `interest` must be defined as `Double`: `Double interest = null;
        do {
            interest = balance * interestRate / 100;
        `

Answer (score -1):

The variable `interest` is declared twice.

Here is a slightly cleaned up version of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoWhile {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("balance: ");
        int balance = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("interestRate: ");
        double interestRate = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("year: ");
        int year = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("press 'N' to exit");
        String input = in.next();
        double interest = 0;    //to define interest

        do
        {
            interest = balance * interestRate / 100;
            balance += interest;
            year++; // print current balance
        }
        while (input.equals("N"));

        System.out.println("interest: " + interest + "balance: " + balance + "year: " + year) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: True, fixed the indent.